# c: reallocate memory pointed by a struct member

Tags: arrays, c, memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
#define DEFAULT_SIZE 100

struct my_struct {
   struct some_struct *ptr;
   size_t len;
   char buf[0];
};

struct my_struct *s;

s = malloc(sizeof *s + DEFAULT_SIZE);
...
```

Now, assuming I want to expand the `buf` memory. Do I need to re-create `struct my_struct *` with `realloc()` call? Can't I simply reallocate memory occupied by `buf`, i.e. :

```
realloc(s->buf, 2* DEFAULT_SIZE);
```

Comment: You mean `void *tmp = realloc(s, sizeof *s + 2 * DEFAULT_SIZE);`. Then check, if `tmp` is not null and assign `s = tmp;`

Comment: You can’t reallocate something you didn’t allocate. If it was a pointer into which you allocated memory separately then that would be different.

Comment: Array size of 0 in a structure is not standard C — it is a GCC extension.  Standard C has flexible array members (FAM).  You specify `char but[];` as the last field in the structure.

Answer (score 1):

No. You can only `realloc` a pointer returned by `malloc`. `malloc` gave you the pointer to the entire structure, so that is what you may `realloc`.